# How can I differentiate my terminals

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, titlebar, prompt

I am using multiple terminals for different task. But it's hard to remember which terminal I use for a specific task. I guess I could set the title, but how and is there something else I can do to differentiate them ?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can differentiate your terminal windows:

- You can set the title.   This can be done in many (possibly conflicting) ways:

  - The xtitle command can emit escape sequences to do this.  (This is so simple, it has been rewritten multiple times over the years, but this is the first one I found when I looked.)
  - Some systems set the default shell prompt to include the same escape sequences to set it to a piece of the current directory. You can edit your shell init file (`.bashrc` for bash) to adjust this.
  - Some tools like screen automatically copy their internal window title to the terminal title.
  - Some terminals allow setting the title within the terminal settings, possibly in profile.
- You can change the size and shape of the terminal to be appropriate for a class of tasks.  For instance, if you are using `top` you might want to make it taller to show more processes.  for `atop` you might also want to make it wider as atop will show additional columns as they fit.
- You can change the font in the terminal.  The specific font might help distinguish it, but you may also want to change the font size, for instance, making important windows you have to read use a larger font and less important windows showing status of some long running job in a smaller font.  In some cases, you don't need to read it, and just the general shape of the text is enough to give a hint of what is going on in the window (and maybe resize it later when you need to read it).
- Some terminals allow changing the foreground and background colors or set background images.  This can help distinguish terminals.
- Most modern graphical terminals support tabbed windows.  Besides setting the title in the tab, you may also be able to change the color or decorations in the tab.
- If you want to go all out, you could install multiple terminal programs, each of which has its own styling and look and feel, so this can distinguish the terminals to some extent.

This list probably leaves out some methods, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a bash tool a while ago for this purpose. It makes your prompt themeable and lets you set GNOME Terminal's title with one command:

```
PS1_Theme <theme_name> <terminal_name>
```

It also lets you push\pop dynamic elements (state) to your prompt. See the screenshot, there's more to see at [GitHub](https://github.com/kristianbenoit/promptmanager).

[image: promptmanager use example]